# How do I restore/recover an RDS instance that is corrupted?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-rds

I attempted to upgrade the RDS DB instance from db.t3.large to db.m6g.large. Although the modification went through successfully, I start getting errors on my web application. For two tables, no matter what I do, I get this error:

> Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

I know what the error is. However, at this point, there is no way to fix it. Anything touching those two tables are corrupted. I even tried to restore the DB using "Point In Time Restore" and it failed. It got stuck at "Creating" and I finally got an email titled "RDS MySQL - Point In Time Restore Failure". Message is

> We have been unable to perform a point-in-time restore for your Amazon RDS DB instance XXX, in the us-west-2 Region for account ID: XXX. As a result, your instance was put in the 'incompatible-restore' state [1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=331151).

When I did restore from past snapshots it works. But the new snapshots still fail for those two tables.

I have posted it on the [AWS developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=331151) but there has been no response for since Nov 12, 2020.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: An example of "no matter what I do" with those two tables.

For example, if I connect to those tables using a SQL client such as SequelPro and I attempt to query those tables, that error pops up. Pretty much and DML that I throw at it will fail.

Ex: `select * from table_name` OR `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: "no matter what I do"  please show what you are actually doing to get that error?

Comment: Can you mysqldump the db?  You could then fix the tables using code or a text editor like Notepad++

Comment: I can start looking into a manual mysqldump and see how that goes. Thank you.